# Slider-like transition effect as div fade-in / out

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

You know like there are some cool slider effects out there that sometimes use cube transition effects. For example, the next image is built up of multiple cubes which fit together at the end of the transition.

Well i was wondering... Is there a jQuery plugin of some sort that uses this transition as a div fade in / fade out?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

- [the Piecemaker](http://activetuts.s3.amazonaws.com/freebies/003_pieceMaker/piecemaker/index.html)
- [this 3D CSS cube](http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/)
- [another rotating cube](http://www.kawa.net/works/js/animation/cube-e.html)
- [or whatever this is](http://www.zachstronaut.com/lab/isocube.html)

Comment: hahaha i love your comment on the last one :P But uhmmm... As specified, i am aware of cube like sliders. How can i use one of these as a fade-in effect for an element?

Comment: It's hard to see what you're imagining in your head, but since you said "fade-in", may I suggest the jQuery method `.fadeIn()`?

Comment: Since i mentioned fadeIn, i already know of .fadeIn() xD. I'm looking for something a little more special. What show effects are out there?

Comment: Sorry, it feels as if this discussion is becoming too open-ended and 'chatty'. The best idea might be to reflect on what it is you want your software to do.